# Sql Timeout expired OnResume mode

Tags: c#, android, sql-server, sql-server-2008, xamarin

I'm sending remote a query, from a mobile into a local Sql server.

```
Btn.Click+=delegate
{
 using(SqlConnection con= new SqlConnection("server=192.xxx.xxx.xxx;database=xxx;user id =xxxx;password=xxxx;Connection Timeout=3)
     {

         using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Inventory (itemName) values (Salad),con);
         {
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

         }
      }
 };
```

Some times,(not always) in random moments when mobile coming back from pause mode in resume mode and i'm clicking immediately btn click, I'm getting this message.(Sql Timeout expired )
Also i have tried SqlAuto Close

```
USE [master]
GO

ALTER DATABASE [AdventureWorks2008R2] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF WITH NO_WAIT
GO
```

It seems like it takes too long to re-establish again SqlConnection.
Is there any trick which i can avoid that? Example to have always wifi connected in pause mode or SqlConnection to be always Establised even my mobile is on pause mode?

Comment: When you are creating the new `SqlConnection`, you are setting `Timeout =3`. Perhaps increase this value?

Comment: If the application is working i dont have any error with connection Time out, the problem is only when i'm coming-from onPause Mode. Also i dont want mobile to wait for  5 seconds or more till SqlConnection will run my query. It doesnt make sense